# Can we use boostrap classes directly in react js render function

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I was able to create react boostrap components within render using react-strap.But I want to know is there anyway to use boostrap classes within render function? I tried it like following.But it did not work.

```html
<div>
<div className="panel panel-default">
  <div className="panel-body">A Basic Panel</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: that should work as long as you've loaded the bootstrap framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to made sure you have Bootstrap loaded like you would when setting up Bootstrap in any other web project in your index.js file see the Bootstrap site and go togetting started, however why not use a React version of Bootstrap.

Offers all the features of Bootstrap but using React approaches.

https://react-bootstrap.netlify.com/

You can find more info on how to add it to your project here.

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-bootstrap/

Comment: Thank you. I was import "boostrap.min.css" instead of "boostrap.css".After changing it to import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'; It worked

Comment: I think you have a different problem that you haven't resolved yet. You should always use the minified version. If the minified version of bootstrap isn't working are you sure you're loading it correctly? Are there any errors?

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap is just a CSS library in a directory (or CDN), right? As long as you link it in your index.html page or import it, it'll be available to use just like your CSS.
React doesn't prevent you from doing non-React things, so don't overthink it.

See: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-bootstrap/

Comment: Thank you. I was import "boostrap.min.css" instead of  "boostrap.css".After changing it to  import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'; It worked